# AndroidX pure unit testing - no instrumentation

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, android-testing, androidx

I'm trying to write purely unit tests that do not in any way instantiate or run the rest of the app, but every single of my tests seem to call `MyApplication`'s `onCreate`. How do i avoid this? I want my test to only run the code i explicitly tell it to.

I have these dependencies for my tests:

```
testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'
def mockito_version = "2.27.0"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito_version"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockito_version"
```

Additionally, I also have specified the test runner in my build.gradle:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

I've tried a couple of different annotations for my tests:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MyTests {
    // ...
}

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyTests {
    // ...
}
```

Both of these seem to instantiate `MyApplication` which I do not want. If i remove the annotation completely, it seems to work correctly except for when using `ApplicationProvider` to get a `Context` instance:

```
IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
```

Is it possible to do raw unit tests in Android using the AndroidX test libraries? If so, how?

Edit: Comments asked for an example of what i want to test:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static String getAdditionString(Context context, int a, int b) {
        int result = a + b;
        return result + context.getString(R.string.mystring);
    }
}
```

I would like to verify that this method returns the expected result, without spinning up the rest of the app

Edit2: Ok so apparently `testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true` seems to cause the runner to instantiate and run my entire app, instead of just making the resources available. Interesting behavior. I guess that changes my question to: How do i use my apps resources in a unittest without this setting?

Comment: You should describe what exactly you want to test, maybe you are using the wrong testing library for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've added an example of what i want to be able to test

Comment: What command are you using to run your tests?

Comment: I right click the test class -> "run test"

Comment: Well if you method requires a context you can't test it totally detached, thats probably why the application is started. Your method is not very suitable for isolated testing.

Comment: Hmm? that's one of the main features of RoboElectric - to let you mock context. My method is very suited for isolated testing